# pandas apply function to corresponding cells of multiple frames

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function to corresponding cells of two identically sized dataFrames to create a new frame.

In pseudocode I'd like to do the following:

```
def someFunction(df1, df2):
  #apply Levenstein.ratio() to the corresponding cells in df1, df2. eg 
  #eg:df1.iloc[0]['colA'] compare to df2.iloc[0]['colA'] etc

frameC= someFunction(frameA, frameB)
```

I could write the nested for loops and iterate over each row/column of the frames to do this, but that would be slow and tedious.  Is there a better way to do this in pandas?  I've been playing around with the df.apply() function and can't seem to figure out how to efficiently compare the corresponding cells of two different dataframes.

Comment: Did you test if looping is actually too slow? (it will depend on the timing of the applied function if the looping will be determinant for speed) And can the function you want to apply be vectorized?

Comment: It wasn't as quick as I wanted it to be - I'm comparing strings across millions of records.  Basically, I'm trying to match people based on name, address, etc.  For each of their fields, I'm comparing the two to see how similar they are.  I can't think of a way to vectorize that.

Comment: If the rows already line up (?), wouldn't it make sense to merge them first?  The code would be more readable and it looks like you are creating a third dataframe anyway.  From the data description it's not clear to me why you would have 2 dataframes rather than 1 in the first place.

Comment: For this version the rows do line up (We're comparing the same people, just over different timeframes).  The columns on the two dfs have the exact same name, so I'd just have to rename columns and somehow track which to compare in the same merged dataset.  However, I can see the writing on the wall that the next question will be to match unbalanced datasets, so I was more trying to figure out the functionality of comparing frames, rather than an exact solution.

Comment: Even if the rows don't exactly line up, you can merge the two datasets based on a certain column that should match to compare them (eg `pd.merge`)